# Getting variable is indefined error inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var all_videos = document.querySelectorAll(".video-feed-item-wrapper");
var all_urls = [];
console.log(all_videos.length);
for(i = 0; i <= all_videos.length; i++) {
  all_urls.push(all_videos[i].getAttribute('href'));
}
console.log(all_urls);
```

It gives me the error `all_videos[i]` is undefined. Why is it undefined?

Thanks.

Comment: Here `i` becomes a global variable use `let`,`var` here `for(i = 0; i <= all_videos.length; i++) {`

Comment: Is there anything in `all_videos` in that console.log call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here , first `i` becomes a global variable and instead `i <= all_videos.length` use only `i < all_videos.length`. It is `undefined` because `i` trying the access the element which is not available. The element is not available because `index` starts from `0`

```
for(i = 0; i < all_videos.length; i++) {
  all_urls.push(all_videos[i].getAttribute('href'));
}
```

Comment: Just removing the the `=` from `<=` resolved the error. :) Are there any cases where keeping `i` global would have become a problem?

Comment: @RealNoob Global variable creates risk in javascript since it can be accessed by other function. For example if in other loop if you use same `i` then there will be a collision . So scoping variable is important

Answer (score 1):

For loop should iterate from 0 to length-1

Condition in `for` loop should be `i < all_videos.length` instead of `i <= all_videos.length`

The correct line should be:

```
for(i = 0; i < all_videos.length; i++) {
```